# Draw a-cylinder between 2 dots with A-frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

i just newbie in a-frame, and i cant find information about it.

I have 2 dots, start and end, ex: `{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}` and `{ x: 10, y: 0, z: 0 }`
How can i place a cylinder between them, or i must do transform with translate and rotate manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When arranging your scene way, it's helpful to use the [A-Frame inspector](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/using-the-aframe-inspector.html) to visually drag things around and resize them. This inspector is be opened with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

In this particular case, the [`tube` component](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/primitives) might actually be closer to what you want. It draws a cylinder along an arbitrary list of points you provide:

```
<a-tube path="5 0 5, 5 0 -5, -5 0 -5" radius="0.5" material="color: red"></a-tube>
```